# Problems in understanding 2008 AMC 12B Problem 19

Tags: complex-numbers, contest-math

A function $f$ is defined by $f(z) = (4 + i) z^2 + \alpha z + \gamma$ for all complex numbers $z$, where $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are complex numbers and $i^2 = - 1$. Suppose that $f(1)$ and $f(i)$ are both real. What is the smallest possible value of $| \alpha | + |\gamma |$ ?

Solution 2 provided by AOPS goes like this:
$f(1)=4+i+\alpha+\gamma$ and
$f(i)=-4-i+\alpha \cdot i +\gamma$

Since $f(1)$ and $f(i)$ are both real we get,$$\alpha+\gamma=-i$$ $$\alpha \cdot i+\gamma=i$$
Solving, we get $\alpha=1-i$, $\gamma$ can be anything, to minimize the value we set $\gamma=0$, so then the answer is $\sqrt{1^2+1^2}=\sqrt{2}$. Thus, the answer is $\sqrt{2}$

However, I don't understand why we can get these equations, since for example if we just say that $\alpha+\gamma=-i$, aren't we assuming that the real part of $\alpha + \gamma = 0$?

Please let me know!

Comment: Yes I know but (+)=−1 does not mean the same thing as +=−, because that would mean that the real portion would have to be 0

Comment: Dude come on I'm not saying I'm right I'm asking whats wrong with my understanding of the problems solution.

Comment: No, you don't need to assume the real part to be zero. The real part can be added to the $4$ or $-4$ as the case might be and you'll still have a real value for the function. What's critical is that the imaginary part cancels.

Comment: Yes I know, but the equation +=− assumes the real part of this addition to be zero when in reality it doesnt need to be right?!

Comment: I see your point and think you're right

Comment: Okay. So then how would we solve this problem?

Comment: There's something I don't quite understand in the proposed solution. Wouldn't $\gamma=0\implies\alpha=-i$ in the first equation and, therefore, $\alpha i=-i^2\ne i$ in the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd do: Consider the real and the imaginary parts of $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ separately $\alpha=\alpha_r+\alpha_i i$, $\gamma=\gamma_r+\gamma_i i $. We have then

\begin{align}
   f(1)&=4 +i+\alpha_r+\alpha_i i+\gamma_r+\gamma_i i\\
   &= (4+\alpha_r+\gamma_r)+(1+\alpha_i+\gamma_i)i
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
   f(i)&=-4 -i+(\alpha_r+\alpha_i i)i+\gamma_r+\gamma_i i\\
   &= (-4-\alpha_i+\gamma_r)-(1-\alpha_r-\gamma_i)i.
\end{align}

In order for the function to take real values,

\begin{align}
   1+\alpha_i+\gamma_i&=0\\
   1-\alpha_r-\gamma_i&=0
\end{align}

We observe right away that $\gamma_r$ can take any value and the solutions will still be real so we set $\gamma_r=0$ to minimize the value. We also observe that
\begin{align}
   \mid\,\alpha\mid+\mid\gamma\mid&=\sqrt{\alpha_r^2+\alpha_i^2}+\sqrt{\gamma_i^2}\\
   &=\{\text{using }\alpha_r=1-\gamma_i\text{ and }\alpha_i=-(1+\gamma_i)\}\\
   &=\sqrt{2+2\gamma_i^2}+\sqrt{\gamma_i^2}. 
\end{align}
This is increasing in $\gamma_i$, so we choose $\gamma_i=0$, which leaves us with $\alpha_r=1$ and $\alpha_i=-1$ and results in $\mid\,\alpha\mid+\mid\gamma\mid=\sqrt{2}$ indeed.

In fact, the solution claims that $\alpha=1-i$ (same as obtained here), i.e., the real part of $\alpha$ is not zero.

Comment: Yea, I did that too, but why can you set $\gamma_{r} = 0$? 
The question mentions that $\gamma, \alpha$ are complex numbers, and if you set $\gamma_{r} = 0$ isn't $\gamma$ purely imaginary?

Comment: Yes, but I believe that imaginary numbers are included in $\Bbb C$ just as reals are. By the same token, would you say that $a+0i\not\in\Bbb C$?

Comment: I guess you are right. Thanks for taking the time